# Bulk update all description categories

Tags: wordpress, categories

I want set the all description categories in one request :

```
    global $wpdb;
    foreach (get_categories() as $cat){ 
    $wpdb->query(
     "
    UPDATE $wpdb->term_taxonomy 
    SET description = '".$cat->cat_name." ' 
    WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id  = '".$cat->term_id."' 
    
    "
 );
```

but without success. any help thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->query('
    UPDATE '.$wpdb->prefix.'term_taxonomy AS tt    
    INNER JOIN
    '.$wpdb->prefix.'terms AS t
    ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
    SET tt.description = t.name              
    WHERE tt.taxonomy = "category"');
```

By the way in your code you have more then one request on each foreach iteration you make a new request

Comment: yes it works like i want , thank you . but i want to know what was the error in my code ?